# Jquery form validation - How not to execute code before validating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a small form with some calculations. Now the calculation are done using button click event.

```
  $('a#check_var').click(function() {
    // the below call the form validation  
    $("#bet_cal_form").valid();
          <- My code here ->
  });
```

Now everything works, problems is I don't want my code to execute unless there are no error in the form validation. Currently I get the error messages but also my code get executed.

Comment: You need an if. `if ($("#bet_cal_form").valid()) { my code here }`

Comment: As @mplungjan said, you need to use the result of that (a boolean) to perform the correct action.

Comment: result of "$("#bet_cal_form").valid()" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an if and to cancel the link and since all IDs need to be unique, you do not need the a in the selector

```
$(function() {
  $("#check_var").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // the below call the form validation  
    if($("#bet_cal_form").valid()) {
      <- My code here ->
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `if` statement, of course.

```
if ($("#bet_cal_form").valid()) {
    // Stuff that should only be done if form is valid
}
```